# striptags but leave link test in between

Tags: templating, richtext, regex

I have a rich text (redactor field) that I'm using striptags on to remove the html markup from the front end. However I noticed for links it whips out the link and the text in between. Is this something I can fix with a regular expression? Can you even do that with a twig filter? If so does anyone have an example?

Here is my code:

```
{% set articleText = myFirstMatrixBlockWithType.blogArticleText %}
{% if articleText | length > 200 %}
    {% set articleTextTrim = articleText | slice(0, 200) ~ '...' %}
    {{ articleTextTrim | striptags }}
{% else %}
    {{ articleText | striptags }} 
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, excluding certain tags from being removed is built into the `striptags` [filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/striptags.html).

You can use it like this:

```
{{ articleTextTrim | striptags('<a>') }}
```

Comment: but then it outputs as html like <a href="www.example.com">link to something</a> I was hope to keep the "link to something" text but remove the html markup.

Comment: A raw filer should stop escaping the link. 

{{ articleTextTrim | striptags('<a>') | raw }}